# Export images from flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, image, export, symbols

First of all let my clarify that I am a flash noob, this is a freelance job I am doing for someone.

I have a flash files with symbols I need to export as PNG images, for some reason the exported images have different width and height than indicated in the flash file.
After checking I found out that the new dimensions don't even keep the original ratio between height and width. This happens for several symbols at different sizes.
What might be the reason for this?

I have also considered finding a way to take a snapshot from within flash of a slice in the flash movie, is that possible?

Understand that I cannot manually take the snapshots as I need this done on a very large quantity of symbols.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to export from the swf or the fla?

Answer (score 5):

Here is one method that just worked for me.

In CS5:

1. Click the image you want to export.
2. Properties -> "edit" - This will open the file in Photoshop.
3. Then you can save it outside of Flash!

Comment: This is annoying if you have like 100 images to export though >_<

Answer (score 1):

You can export images through the export menu (assuming you have a version >= CS3).

Just go File>Export>Export Image and select your settings from there. It should autocrop to the current width/height of the graphic symbol if you have the symbol selected.

Comment: Unfortunately (and obviously) I have tried that solution as it is the normal way for exporting images, my problem is that although I have selected the wanted symbol Flash does not autocrop it to the right size, setting the size myself results in unexpected parts of the images being cropped out which is not a desired behaviour.

Comment: If you could upload the FLA and send it over, I'll take a look at it and see what I can do.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I needed ;d - Just copy the symbol you want to save - into a new .fla and use this command.

Answer (score 1):

This might answer your second question ("take a snapshot of a slice in the flash movie"): I made the following script to bulk-export PNGs from flash, one for each frame in the main timeline.

[flash-export jsfl script](https://github.com/jrrbru/flash-export)

This code is derived from [a script I found online to do the same thing](http://journal.reallyenglish.com/2010/01/30/batch-image-exporting-from-fla.html)

Answer (score 0):

To help with your problem:

-take everyting on the stage and place it into a single container movieclip

-make a shape object with the dimensions of the image you want to export

-make that shape object the background in the container clip.

-Change the stage to the dimensions of the container clip.

-export your movie as an image.